# Correct way to handle CGImageRef in containers under ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, cgimageref, toll-free-bridging

I am new to incorporating arc in my projects. I am trying to understand __bridge and its little friends so that I can properly cast my CGImageRef's when adding and removing them from containers.

I am getting a "Potential leak of an object stored…" on one of my lines. Here is the basic cycle of my code:

```
CGImageRef renderedRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
[_array addObject: (__bridge_transfer id)renderedRef];//_array is an iVar
```

then somewhere down the road I do this:

```
    CGImageRef iRef = (__bridge_retained CGImageRef)array[0];
//then I do something fancy with iRef
//at the end of the method, I get "Potential leak of an object stored…"
//I have no idea what to do
//I've tried CGImageRelease(iRef); but it still doesn't change the warning.
```

Can someone shed some light on this? Also, I have tried just using __bridge but that doesn't make a difference.

**Edit 1:**

I expanded the analyzer results and followed what was happening. It was because I was using iRef in a method like so: [self doSomethingFancy:iRef]; and in that method, iRef was being retained but not released. So that fixes the warning, but I'm still a bit puzzled.

I am not quite clear on when to use the various __bridge casts. Under ARC, does the following increase the reference count?

```
CGImageRef iRef = (__bridge CGImageRef)array[0];
```

Also, at some point if I tell my _array iVar to removeAllObjects, will that decrement their reference counts properly?

Comment: `CGImageRelease(iRef)` is correct here. If you still have a warning, click on the blue icon to get a detailed report about what the Analyzer thinks.

Comment: @MartinR I updated my question to reflect my findings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// This WILL NOT increment the image's retain count.
CGImageRef iRef = (__bridge CGImageRef)array[0];

// This WILL increment the image's retain count.
CGImageRef iRef = (__bridge_retained CGImageRef)array[0];
```

Since `__bridge_retained` increments the retain count, you need to decrement the retain count at some point later.  Because `__bridge_retained` acts like `CFRetain`, Apple created a `__bridge_retained` wrapper called `CFBridgingRetain` that reminds you of this:

```
// This WILL increment the image's retain count.
CGImageRef iRef = CFBridgingRetain(array[0]);
```

Whenever you see `CFRetain` **or** `CFBridgingRetain`, you know you need to release the object at some point later.

Similarly, you can use `CFBridgingRelease` instead of `__bridge_transfer` to decrement the retain count of a CF object.  Example:

```
[_array addObject:CFBridgingRelease(renderedRef)];
```

You can use `CFBridgingRelease` to balance a `CFRetain` or a `CFBridgingRetain`.  It returns an `id` that ARC manages.

A normal `NSMutableArray` retains each of its elements.  You can tell it to become empty:

```
[_array removeAllObjects];
```

When you do this, it will release each of its elements, balancing the retain it performed on each element.

Thus there is no memory leak in this code:

```
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(...);
[_array addObject:CFBridgingRelease(image)];
[_array removeAllObjects];
```

or in this code:

```
CGImageRef image = CGImageCreate(...);
[_array addObject:CFBridgingRelease(image)];

CGImageRef image2 = CFBridgingRetain([_array lastObject]);
[_array removeLastObject];
CGContextDrawImage(gc, rect, image2);
CGImageRelease(image2);
```

Comment: Fantastic, this is the best explanation I've seen of this sticky issue. Thanks Rob